# Java reflection: constructor for primitive int causes: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.<init>(int)

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, constructor

When I try to get the constructor to create an `int` it throws a: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.<init>(int)`

A very simplified version of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
Class myClass = int.class;
Constructor ctor = myClass.getConstructor(int.class);
```

I've tried the following as well:

```
Constructor ctor = myClass.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE);
```

```
Constructor ctor = myClass.getConstructor(Integer.class);
```

to end up with the same exception. What could be causing this?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the replies. I'm including the extended example below.

I'm trying to do the above while trying to invoke an unknown setter of an object, where I only have the value to pass to the setter as a String.

**EDIT AFTER RESOLUTION**
Please note that below code is only for clarity/context, and edited for brevity.

Thanks for the replies. What I really eventually needed was if there was a way to create a primitive (e.g. int) with methods related to reflection. The chosen answer provides a way using the corresponding wrapper class.

```
public class MyClass {
    int field; 

    public void setField(int field) {
        this.field = field; 
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) { 
        String value = "3"; // String of the the int value I want to pass to my setter as an argument when I invoke it via reflection
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        
        Class objClass = myObject.getClass();
        
        Method method = ... // Resolve the setter method using objClass.getMethods(); omitted here for brevity            
        Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        Class paramType = paramTypes[0]; // My setter method takes only one argument; so pick the first one

        if (paramType.getName().equals("int")) {
            Constructor ctor = paramType.getConstructor(int.class); // CAUSES EXCEPTION

            Object instance = ctor.newInstance(value);

            method.invoke(myObj, instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's a lot easier to help if we can simply reproduce the problem first.

Comment: What is `myClass`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, luk2302, Sorry, I had added only part of the sample I'd intended to. The sample-code is now updated.

Comment: You want to access the constructor of the primitive `int`?

Comment: `Class myClass = int.class;` doesn't look right as `myClass` doesn't hold `Class` with metadata about `YourClass` but about `int` type (which is *primitive* and doesn't have any methods nor constructors which is why you are getting the exception). You probably meant something along `Class myClass = MyClass.class;`.

Comment: @luk2302, yes, basically. I want to access the constructor for primitive int.

Comment: "*I want to access the constructor for primitive int*" that looks like strong candidate for [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why do you think you need such functionality? What you *really* want to achieve here?

Comment: @Pshemo, no, what I want to do is to create a primitive int, via reflection.

Comment: But what would be the point? At the moment you would invoke such constructor (assuming it exists) you still would need to pass some `int` value *which already exists* so can be used instead (making reflection redundant for that case).

Comment: @Pshemo, I'm doing the above while invoking a setter method of some other class. When the setter has a parameter of type: int, I wan't to create an int (with a String representation of that int I have, e.g.: "3"), and invoke the setter method (via reflection) passing it the primitive int I just created.

Comment: Pass it as an Integer instead. That's how reflection with primitives works. (Note that if you'd told us what you were *really* trying to do from the start, and provided a [mcve] of that, we'd have reached the end much earlier.)

Comment: If your goal is to change `String` `"3"` into `int` `3` then you can parse it with `int value = Integer.parseInt(stringRepresentingInt);`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Pshermo, I've edited the question with an extended example.

Comment: But *still* not a complete example. You haven't shown the method you're trying to call, so we can't just copy/paste/compile and see it fail, then fix it and see it work. Fundamentally, you just need to create an `Integer` and pass that when calling `method.invoke`...

Comment: @Pshemo, yes I could, but I'm sort of interested in knowing how to properly "instantiate" an int via reflection.

Comment: @Miy: You can't. What type of variable would you store it in? `Object`, presumably, at which point you've got an `Integer`... (If you're assigning it to an `int` variable then use one of the normal ways of computing an `int`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I've extended the example even further. Obviously, I've made it very succinct , but the gist is, I only know the name of the setter of MyClass (but not the TYPE of argument it takes), and the String representation of the value I should supply as the argument. I want to instantiate an int to supply as the argument if the method turns out to take an int.

Comment: "*but I'm sort of interested in knowing how to properly "instantiate" an int via reflection*" you can't do properly something which can't be done at all. `int` is primitive type so it doesn't have constructor like `new int(1)` which you could try to emulate via reflection. Instance is representation of *class* but `int` is not a class, it is a *primitive* type. To create int from String use `Integer.parseInt(stringValue)`.

Comment: @Miy: And as I keep saying: you pass in an `Integer`. But thank you for now providing a *nearly complete* example. Except it's still not actually complete because of the "..." part. I still don't know why you think there *is* an `int(String)` constructor that you're trying to call... but you could definitely use `Object instance = Integer.parseInt(value);` instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you; I could appreciate why you must be wondering why I'm not choosing the obvious Integer.parseInt(..) and get it over with. 

But, the above extended code is only the context. As a noob to Reflection my initial problem was if there was really a way to create a primitive with reflection (and what the closest way to do that via reflection). 

And most importantly, why Java's API for [Class.getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)] doesn't work here, even though the supplied arguments are "apparently" valid (a class object, albeit that of a primitive type -- int.class).

Comment: What constructors do you expect `int` to have? Have you ever seen code written as `int x = new int("3");`? You can't create a primitive with reflection, because reflection is always expressed in terms of `Object`, and as soon as you try to assign a primitive to `Object`, you end up with the wrapper type (`Integer` etc) which is why we've been suggesting you use `Integer` all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type and unlikely has the same kind of initialisation as reference types do (with a constructor). I don't think it has either `int.<init>(int)` or `int.<int>()` declared and available via Reflection API.

That said, you can do the trick with its wrapper class `Integer` because it has a constructor `Integer(int)` defined.

```
Constructor<Integer> constructor = Integer.class.getConstructor(int.class);
Integer integer = constructor.newInstance(3);
System.out.println(integer); // prints out 3
```

Comment: This works, and this seems to be the closest there is to create a primitive int using Constructor.newInstance(). 

When you look at the method signature of Class.getConstructor(), you get the impression that it accepts any Class in the Class-vararg it takes as the argument, but it as you've said, it doesn't work with arguments such as: int.class. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Correction: "...the closest there is to create an int _using an argument of primitive-int class-object_ to  Constructor.newInstance()"

Comment: @Miy: No, it's fine to pass `int.class` into `Class.getConstructor` *when you're talking about a class with a constructor that has an `int` parameter*. But you're trying to call `getConstructor` *on* `int.class`, which doesn't have any constructors.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, you're spot on. I wasn't familiar with the specifics of "class-objects of primitives" (e.g. `int.class`) and how they differ from that of a proper object. The documentation of `Class.getConstructor()` API _is_ accurate, but doesn't mention/highlight this outright.

Comment: Using `Integer`’s constructor via Reflection is as discouraged as using it without. Calling the `valueOf` method via Reflection is not harder than using the constructor. The still open question is what kind of problem this will solve. Using `Integer.class` instead of `int.class` still requires awareness of this case, so the OP could still use `Integer integer = 3;` in that case. It’s adding fuel to the flames that the OP actually has a *string* as input.